# How to execute Cplex Run Configuration without IDE

Tags: cplex, opl

I don't know if this is possible or not, but I would like to execute a run configuration of my Cplex project without opening the project in the Cplex IDE and running it from there.

Can I somehow double click something that runs the configuration or maybe a batch file with command line that executes the run configuration?

Any help / ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.5.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_syntax_commandline.html

That link seems helpful, but I don't know how it works exactly: 

'-p' in Command Line: 
Meaning: "project-dir: [run configuration]"
Description: "Executes the run configuration of the project identified by its path. If you do not specify a run configuration, the default one is executed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute OPL projects from the command line you can use [oplrun](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_TOP.html). The most [basic usage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_syntax_basic.html) is as follows:

```
oplrun [options] "model-file" "[data-file ...]"
```

To execute a specific run configuration in a project, follow this syntax:

```
oplrun [options] -p project-dir [run-configuration]
```

To find out more, see the documentation for [run configurations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/gsoplide/topics/opl_ide_gs_tut_execute_proj.html) and the `oplrun` [command line options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplrun/topics/oplrun_syntax_commandline.html). In particular, see the `-ph` option which:

> Displays the run configurations available in the specified project.
>   This is most useful on Unix platforms, where one cannot view this
>   information in the CPLEX Studio IDE.

If you don't know what the names of your run configurations are, try running with the `-ph` option to get a listing.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942964/how-to-change-cplex-parameters-in-oplrun) related question.

Comment: If a client didn't have Cplex Studio IDE installed on their system. What's the least amount of necessary steps they'd have to take to make "oplrun" work for them? @rkersh

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I believe that the client would have to purchase a deployment edition license (which _should_ include `oplrun`). See [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=99dcc201-f8c9-4fd7-a232-aab68df474ab) post from the official IBM developerWorks forum.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) @rkersh